# What is a good architecture to run 50k AWS lambdas in parallel and publish a message in a AWS-IoT core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, aws-step-functions, aws-iot

I am developing a solution that simulates 50K or more devices publishing a message in AWS-IoT core.

The final goal is to stress our system to this limit because we are expecting that ammount soon and I need to know how it will behavior a that point.

I was investigating the possible solutions and I found a service created by AWS called [IoT Device Simulator](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/iot-device-simulator/) but it does not fulfill the 50k parallel requirements. It allows only `100 devices`- [see simulation limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/iot-device-simulator/considerations.html).

In fact it is using the following architecture:
[image]

Here we can see [the code that this solution is using](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/device-simulation-with-aws-iot-and-aws-lambda/). It is using a loop to publish the message. Even though it is some milliseconds of difference it is not a concurrent call in the same millisecond.

The bottleneck here is the steps 7 to 9. My question is, how could I trig or dispatch 50K lambdas in the step 7 using stepfunctions concurrently? I don`t know if it is possible. If not how could I achieve that functionality.

Comment: For a start, you would need to increase the default limit of 1000 concurrent Lambda executions. I would be skeptical whether they would be willing to increase your limit to 50,000 concurrent executions. Instead, you might consider using EC2 instances with many processes running in parallel.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this is a good point. This is not something impossible. I did request a increase to 100k and all was good. Ec2 is an option but how to create 50k treads inside an Ec2?

Comment: Use multi-threading in your preferred language and/or run multiple concurrent programs. Would work better on Instance Types with more CPUs. You can even use multiple EC2 instances.